# Combine 2 columns in one and add a column to put remarks using if or case in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have 3 tables.

[image]

I want to get this result

[image]

I have tried union tables and it worked. I just need to combine 2 columns (Num_Typ) and (Add_Typ) in one column (Type) then if address or phone number is not available then display N/A. Next I will add a column (Remarks) depending on whether they have an address , a phone number or both, address only or phone only.

Here is the Query

```
SELECT
A.NAMES, 
A.CODE, 
B.NUM_TYP, 
B.PHONE_NUN, 
B.ADD_TYP, 
B.ADDR
FROM NAMES A LEFT JOIN

(
SELECT PHONE.ID, PHONE.NUM_TYP, PHONE.PHONE_NUM, ADDRESS.ADD_TYP, ADDRESS.ADDR
FROM PHONE LEFT JOIN ADDRESS ON (PHONE.NUM_TYP = ADDRESS.ADD_TYP) AND (PHONE.ID = ADDRESS.ID)

UNION
SELECT ADDRESS.ID, PHONE.USG_TYP, PHONE.PHONE_NUM, ADDRESS.ADD_TYP, ADDRESS.ADDR
FROM ADDRESS LEFT JOIN PHONE ON (ADDRESS.ADD_TYP = PHONE.NUM_TYP) AND (ADDRESS.ID = PHONE.ID)) AS B ON A.ID = B.ID;
```

Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: we can't see any image

Comment: It is showing here. You dont have to thumbs down if you cant see because it is showing in mine.

Comment: it was not me :)

Comment: I thumbs it up though

Comment: Is this for MySQL or MSSQLServer? Or are you really trying to write code to work in both? If applies to one RDBMS then update your tags (eg, drop sql-server if this is for MySQL); please (re)check your column names and the query, eg: desired result column headers don't match your select statement ... query references PHONE.USG_TYPE but no such column exists in the Phone table; would also suggest you consider providing table DDL and sample data (possibly as a [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `CASE` expression to your query which renders the message you want:

```
SELECT
    A.NAMES, 
    A.CODE, 
    B.NUM_TYP, 
    B.PHONE_NUN, 
    B.ADD_TYP, 
    B.ADDR,
    CASE WHEN B.PHONE_NUN IS NOT NULL AND B.ADDR IS NULL
         THEN 'MEMBER HAS PHONE ONLY'
         WHEN B.ADDR IS NOT NULL AND B.PHONE_NUM IS NULL
         THEN 'MEMBER HAS ADDR ONLY'
         WHEN B.PHONE_NUN IS NOT NULL AND B.ADDR IS NOT NULL
         THEN 'MEMBER HAS BOTH' END AS REMARKS
FROM NAMES A
LEFT JOIN ...
```

Comment: iI have used it to columns as well.